# Reason for passing function to self executing function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got js code from a design company, but I do not understand the reason for passing a function to a self executing function.

Here is the outline of the code.

```
(function(core) {
   if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
       define("abc", function() {
           var abc;
           abc = window.Abc || core(window, window.jQuery, window.document);
           abc.load = function(res, req, onload, config) {
               var base, i, load, resource, resources;
               resources = res.split(",");
               load = [];
               base = (config.config && config.config.abc && config.config.abc.base ? config.config.abc.base : "").replace(/\/+$/g, "");
               if (!base) {
                   throw new Error("Please define base path to Abc in the requirejs config.");
               }
               i = 0;
               while (i < resources.length) {
                   resource = resources[i].replace(/\./g, "/");
                   load.push(base + "/components/" + resource);
                   i += 1;
               }
               req(load, function() {
                   onload(abc);
               });
           };
           return abc;
       });
   }
   if (!window.jQuery) {
       throw new Error("Abc requires jQuery");
   }
   if (window && window.jQuery) {
       core(window, window.jQuery, window.document);
   }
})(function(global, $, doc) {
   var _c = {};
   ...
   return _c;
});
```

Is there benefit of writing code such way over something like below?

```
(function( core, $, undefined) { 
   ... 
} (window.core= window.core|| {}, jQuery )};
```

Comment: In your example it is create object `_c` and passing it to IIFE, No its not an advanced technique

Comment: Can you post some of the code in function(core) {}?  That might give us a clue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this some advanced technique?

Basically, ....kinda.

In Javascript, functions are treated as first-class objects. This means you can pass them around in variables and whatnot. The first part, `(function(core) { ... })`, creates an anonymous function, taking a single argument called `core`. The parentheses around the function basically just resolve to a `function`. The second part, `(function(global, $, doc) { ... })`, is creating another function, which is passed immediately into a call to the first function as the value of `core`.

Put this way, here's what's happening.

```
// Define the first function (the one that takes core)
var firstFunc = function (core) { /* ... */ };

// Define the second function (the one that takes global, $, and doc)
var secondFunc = function (global, $, doc) { 
    var _c = {};
    /* ... */ 
    return _c;
};

// Call the first, passing in the second.
firstFunc(secondFunc);
```

The above code and the code you posted accomplish the same thing. One purpose for writing something like this would be to sandbox the second function so that the first can specify its own local versions of variables `global`, `$`, and `doc`, which avoids conflicts with, say, active-running versions of jQuery (which typically declares its own globally-scoped `$` variable).

**EDIT**: Now that the code in the first function has been filled in, we can say for sure that the reason for doing this is to resolve dependencies and ensure they are present before manually passing them into the second function. From the look of the code provided, it appears that this is enforcing the presence of `abc` (which I'm assuming is some dependency) via [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), as well as ensuring that jQuery is present. In addition, it looks like the values in `_c` returned from the function are used as a part of that dependency enforcement process, though I can't tell exactly how by looking at it.

Comment: what is the benefit of passing a second function that creates an object instead of just creating the object in the first function?

Comment: As I added in my last edit, it's to be able to use custom versions of `global`, `$` and `doc`, essentially sandboxing the code to prevent it from using the default install of jQuery (or whatever else uses `$`) and accessing the global `document` or `global` scope variables.

Comment: @starcookie I'm not saying you did, but whoever did never left a comment.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Given the code that we see here, yes; they would all be undefined. However, I was assuming that the first function called the second one, and that it provided the appropriate values. From what the OP wrote, it's not even clear the first function does anything with the second function, so this is all speculative. I suppose I should have made that more clear in my answer.

Comment: Due to the edits the OP made to his post, it's more clear what the first function intends to accomplish. I've edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Shotgun. I am not 100% clear yet, but your comment helped me understand a lot better.